# Polars: Select all rows with missing values in any column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

I am working with a DataFrame that contains missing values. As I want to better understand the entries with missing values, I'd like to filter for rows that contain missing values *in any column*.

In pandas, I would've used something along the lines of.

```
df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), :]
```

---

**MRE.**

Given the following DataFrame, I'd expect to see rows 3, 4, and 5 after applying the filter.

```
import polars as pl

# input
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, None, 4, 5],
    "b": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, None, 5.0],
    "c": ["a", "b", None, "d", None],
})

# expected output
df_expected = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [None, 4, 5],
    "b": [3.0, None, 5.0],
    "c": [None, "d", None],
})
```

Comment: Great first question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

In polars, this can be achieved using [`pl.any_horizontal`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html) as follows:

```
df_missing = (
    df
    .filter(
        pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null())
    )
)
```

Note that in this case [`pl.all()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all.html) is just syntactic sugar for `pl.col("*")`.